# Can't seem to download JDK 8, can only download JRE 8

Tags: java

I want to do some programming on my own with java but I can't seem to get JDK 8 onto my computer. I go through the normal process of downloading JDK but at the end of the installation I only ever have JRE, and not JDK. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong as I'm taking all the correct steps when I download JDK.

My laptop is 64 bit and runs on windows 8.1

Comment: this question is off-topic here, however, what your install file name? or where the link that you download your jdk

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/wavezhang/ba8425f24a968ec9b2a8619d7c2d86a6.

Answer (score 1):

Java JDK 8 is available at :

- [direct link](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u51-b16/jdk-8u51-windows-x64.exe)
- [Oracle Website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

To ensure jdk is installed, just go througt the following :

1. press `Win` + `R`
2. type 'cmd' in the popup and press button OK.
3. in the console which has oppened, type `javac -version` and press `enter`.

You should see as an output :

javac 1.8.0_XX

If so sdk is installed.

Comment: OP will only be able to run `javac -version` if the `PATH` variable was set accordingly. In case it does not work, try running `C:\Path\to\your\JDK\bin\javac.exe -version`

Comment: Windows installer used to set `JAVA_HOME` variable.