# Can't download JDK 8

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, sdk

I'm trying to setup Unity to build for Android. But I can't get the Java Development Kit. Can't download it and can't find it either.

[In this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31506112/cant-seem-to-download-jdk-8-can-only-download-jre-8), the guy says

*To ensure JDK is installed, just go through the following :
press Win + R
type 'cmd' in the popup and press button OK.
in the console which has opened, type javac -version and press enter.
You should see as an output :
javac 1.8.0_XX
**If so SDK is installed**.*

I did that and I got "javac 1.8.0_XX", and so I assumed I had the JDK, so I went to **Unity > External Tools > JDK** and tried linking the following path: "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0", and got the error message: "The path you specified does not look like a valid JDK installation. Android development requires at least JDK(1.7), having JRE only is not enough. Please make sure you are selecting a suitable JDK home directory or download and install the latest JDK: [link](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/)"

**I clicked the download link for windows x64 and it never loads and eventually says there's no connection. I tried the x86 as well.**

In this SO question [How do I find where JDK is installed on my windows machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681090/how-do-i-find-where-jdk-is-installed-on-my-windows-machine)

**Answer:** For windows, in the command prompt:

```
c:\> for %i in (java.exe) do @echo.   %~$PATH:i
```

And so I did that and got the path "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe"

When I try linking via **Unity > External tools > JDK** it doesn't find any files.

I'm a bit clueless now.

Comment: Can you tell me What folders are under your C:\Program Files\Java ?

Comment: Only one: jre1.8.0_151. So probably I don't have the JDK, but downloading isn't working either. I read that in some countries Java or JDK isn't available, but my country is listed in this link: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javase7locales-334809.html

Comment: I just tried and able to download 8u151 version. This might be issue with your internet. Make sure some proxy or firewall is not blocking it.

Comment: If oracle links are not working for you, then u can try other websites like filehippo https://filehippo.com/download_java_development_kit/

Comment: Try and let me know if my answer helped you fix the issue?

Comment: Yes. The download doesn't lead anywhere but I think it does it "silently"? After uninstalling Java I looked for it to see if it was removed, found JavaSetup8u151.exe so I ran that, and just installed Java 8 again. Still all I see is that jre folder.

Comment: Where did u found JavaSetup8u151.exe? In your own computer?

Comment: On my pc yes, in the "search". The download worked from filehippo, I'll see if it works now.

Comment: I think the one on your PC is JRE only. Try the one from File hippo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@RealAnyOne, you have installed Java with JRE only installation i.e., without out a JDK that’s what you see only one folder and this is why it also showing version in the command line since it won’t check for JDK. JRE is Java Runtime Environment, JDK is Java Development Kit which contains many essential libraries. So Ideally there should be two folders JRE and JDK. This is the reason you are getting this issue with Unity.

To Fix::

1. Uninstall old Java 8
2. Download Java 8 from the oracle website 
   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html
3. Install it. Now you should have two folders. Then point your Unity to it.

Comment: The download from filehippo worked, thank you very much. Oracle links aren't loading for me.

Comment: I've downloaded Java many times, but this is the first time it is redirecting to the Oracle Sign In page. Trying to download Java 8, did it reach EOL? It says, "The Oracle JDK License has changed for releases starting April 16, 2019.", am a little confused. Any help?